# Subclass `pathlib.Path` fails

Tags: oop, python-3.4

I would like to enhance the class `pathlib.Path` but the simple example above dose not work.

```
from pathlib import Path

class PPath(Path):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

test = PPath("dir", "test.txt")
```

Here is the error message I have.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/projetmbc/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    test = PPath("dir", "test.txt")
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.4/pathlib.py", line 907, in __new__
    self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.4/pathlib.py", line 589, in _from_parts
    drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.4/pathlib.py", line 582, in _parse_args
    return cls._flavour.parse_parts(parts)
AttributeError: type object 'PPath' has no attribute '_flavour'
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible solutions to the problem have been outlined on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162426/subclassing-pathlib-path). You can follow the discussion of the [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue24132). Maybe one day they will post a solution we haven't encountered yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this !

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can subclass the concrete implementation, so this works:

```
class Path(type(pathlib.Path())):
```

Here's what I did with this:

```
import pathlib

class Path(type(pathlib.Path())):
    def open(self, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None):
        if encoding is None and 'b' not in mode:
            encoding = 'utf-8'
        return super().open(mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline)

Path('/tmp/a.txt').write_text("я")
```

Comment: Thanks. It is ugly but far less than my previous method.

Comment: Unfortunately mypy does not allow dynamic base classes, so you can't type check this

Comment: Calling `Path()` creates either a `WindowsPath` or a `PosixPath` object, so the only "magic" that this is doing is determining which flavor to use, then getting that type for the inheritance. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path).

Answer (score 12):

[Here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/151cab576cab/Lib/pathlib.py#l947) is the definition of the `Path` class.  It does something rather clever.  Rather than directly returning an instance of `Path` from its `__new__()`, it returns an instance of a subclass, but *only* if it's been invoked directly as `Path()` (and not as a subclass).

Otherwise, it expects to have been invoked via either `WindowsPath()` or `PosixPath()`, which both provide a `_flavour` class attribute via multiple inheritance.  You must also provide this attribute when subclassing.  You'll probably need to instantiate and/or subclass the [`_Flavour`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/151cab576cab/Lib/pathlib.py#l44) class to do this.  This is not a supported part of the API, so your code might break in a future version of Python.

**TL;DR**: [This idea is fraught with peril, and I fear that my answers to your questions will be interpreted as approval rather than reluctant assistance.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/07/22/10041190.aspx)

Comment: What a weird choice regarding to the traditional Python API. I think that I have to do what you suggest. This needs to read the source. Not a problem but just a little boring thing.

Comment: @projetmbc: IMHO this is poor design; a superclass should not display knowledge of its subclasses, much less *depend on them* in this fashion.  `Path()` ought to be a factory function instead.  It might be worth a bug report, but since it's a matter of subjective opinion, I'm not sure the bug tracker is the best place to start.  You might have a more productive conversation on [Python-Dev](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev) or another mailing list.

Comment: I think like you and I have posted a message on the Python-dev mailing list. On the other the challenge in my answer is a funny thing to do.

Comment: I wouldn't call this clever

Answer (score 10):

Combining some of the previous answers you could also just write:

```py
class MyPath(pathlib.Path):
    _flavour = type(pathlib.Path())._flavour
```

Comment: It seems the most elegant solution to me

Answer (score 8):

You may be able to simplify your life depending on why you want to extend Path (or PosixPath, or WindowsPath). In my case, I wanted to implement a File class that had all the methods of Path, and a few others. However, I didn't actually care if isinstance(File(), Path).

Delegation works beautifully:

```
class File:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = pathlib.Path(path)
        ...

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.path, attr)

    def foobar(self):
        ...
```

Now, if file = File('/a/b/c'), I can use the entire Path interface on file, and also do file.foobar().

Comment: Don't you need a `self.path = pathlib.Path(path)` in `__init__` if you're going to instantiate with `file = File("a/b/c")`, i.e. a `str` argument to `__init__`'s `path` argument?

Comment: Sure, self.path needs to be a pathlib.Path.

Comment: Okay, you should adjust that in your answer (doesn't work as it stands right now).

Comment: Okay, I fixed __init__.

Answer (score 6):

I have been struggling with this too.

Here is what i did, studying from the pathlib module.
Seems to me that is the cleaner way to do it, but if the pathlib module changes its implementation, it probably won't hold.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pathlib

class PPath(Path):

    _flavour = pathlib._windows_flavour if os.name == 'nt' else pathlib._posix_flavour

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return super(PPath, cls).__new__(cls, *args)

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__() #Path.__init__ does not take any arg (all is done in new)
        self._some_instance_ppath_value = self.exists() #Path method

    def some_ppath_method(self, *args):
        pass

test = PPath("dir", "test.txt")
```

Answer (score 3):

### Note

I have opened [a bug track here](http://bugs.python.org/issue24132) after a little discussion on the Python dev. list.

### A temporary solution

Sorry for this double answer but here is a way to achieve what I want. Thanks to Kevin  that points me to the source of `pathlib` and the fact we have here constructors.

```
import pathlib
import os

def _extramethod(cls, n):
    print("=== "*n)

class PathPlus(pathlib.Path):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if cls is PathPlus:
            cls = pathlib.WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else pathlib.PosixPath

        setattr(cls, "extramethod", _extramethod)

        return cls._from_parts(args)

test = PathPlus("C:", "Users", "projetmbc", "onefile.ext")

print("File ?", test.is_file())
print("Dir  ?", test.is_dir())
print("New name:", test.with_name("new.name"))
print("Drive ?", test.drive)

test.extramethod(4)
```

This prints the following lines.

```
File ? False
Dir  ? False
New name: C:/Users/projetmbc/new.name
Drive ? 
=== === === ===
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a great idea.  You're basically attaching the extra method to the `WindowsPath` or `PosixPath` classes directly, meaning it'll be available to all instances of those classes, not just the instances created via `PathPlus`.

Comment: I think like you but for the moment this not so perfect solution is the one I use. Why ? If I use my enhanced version of the class Path, I do not care of the Windowsäth or PosixPath. Indeed, on the Python-dev mailing list, Guido himself saids that the subclassing of the class Path must be easier to do that it is now. As a conclusion, my solution is very temporary patch before Path become more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

In order to inherit from `pathlib.Path`, you need to specify which OS, or "flavour" you're representing. All you need to do is specify that you are using either Windows or Unix (seems to be Unix based on your traceback) by inheriting from `pathlib.PosixPath` or `pathlib.WindowsPath`.

```
import pathlib

class PPath(pathlib.PosixPath):
    pass

test = PPath("dir", "test.txt")
print(test)
```

Which outputs:

```
dir\test.txt
```

Using `type(pathlib.Path())` as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34116756/10792235) does the exact same thing as directly inheriting from `pathlib.PosixPath` or `pathlib.WindowsPath` since instantiating `pathlib.Path` "creates either a PosixPath or a WindowsPath" ([pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path)).

If you know your application will not be cross-platform, it is simpler to directly inherit from the flavor Path that represents your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do things regarding to the observation made by Kevin.

```
class PPath():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.path = Path(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then I will need to use a trick so as to automatically bind all the Path's methods to my PPpath class. I think that will be funny to do.

Comment: Re automatic binding: Try overriding `__getattr__`.  This won't catch magic methods, so you'll also need to override `__div__` and (possibly) `__rdiv__` to get the `foo / bar` syntax.

Comment: `__div__` isn't a thing in 3.x.  I meant to say `__truediv__` and maybe `__rtruediv__`.

Comment: I have updated my code so as to automatically have de `div` syntax. My main problem becomes now to find an automatic way to bind all the public method of `Path` like `is_file`  to my class.

Comment: Again, use `__getattr__` to redirect attribute access to the `Path` object.  This will affect normal methods as well.

Comment: I will try this during the coming week. If I find something useful, I'll put it here.

Answer (score 0):

It's work too.

```
from pathlib import Path

class SystemConfigPath(type(Path())):
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        path = cls._std_etc()
        return super().__new__(cls, path, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def _std_etc():
        return '/etc'

name = SystemConfigPath()
name = name / 'apt'
print(name)
```

Printed:

```
/etc/apt
```

@staticmethod can be replaced by @classmethod