# How to access to names of functions defined before a class within the class

Tags: python-3.x, code-inspection

Let's consider the following file `myfile.py`.

```
def f_1():
    print("Run !")

def f_2():
    print("Run, run !")

class Test():
    def __new__(cls):
        print("In the class", dir())

print("After class", dir())
Test()
```

I would like to access to all the functions defined before my class within it. The inside dir is about the class and not the file as the output above shows.

```
After class ['Test', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'f_1', 'f_2']
In the class ['cls']
```

One solution would be to add a global constant `previousnames = dir()` just before the class but is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's better to be explicit about this type of thing; just maintain (with a known name) a list or dictionary of the global functions that `Test` needs access to, and let `Test` iterate over the known list/dictionary.

Comment: I want to add methods to a class but I have no way to subclass it. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29880095/4589608) to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment: be explicit, and don't try to do dynamic function discovery. `dir` is not intended for programmatic use anyway; it's a helper for use in the interactive shell.

```
def f_1():
    print("Run !")

def f_2():
    print("Run, run !")

for_Test = [f_1, f_2]

class Test():
    def __new__(cls):
        for f in for_Test:
            # Based on your linked question
            setattr(cls, f.name, f)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does the job. I will be more explicit in the future. ;-)