# Execute pytest fixture teardown if debugging is quit

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, pytest

## The Problem

I set up a simple test like

```
import pytest
import pathlib


@pytest.fixture
def some_resource():
    testdir = pathlib.Path("i_want_to_be_deleted")
    testdir.mkdir()
    yield
    testdir.rmdir()


def test_dummy_succeeds(some_resource):
    assert pathlib.Path("i_want_to_be_deleted").exists()


def test_dummy_fails(some_resource):
    assert False
```

If I run this test using `pytest`, the directory `i_want_to_be_deleted` is created for the test, and deleted afterwards (also for the failed test). This is as expected.

But if I set a breakpoint somewhere after directory creation, run this in the debugger, and stop the debugging, the directory `i_want_to_be_deleted` persists.

Enhancing this example by implementing a context manager, as suggested in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64008781) by @[BramAppel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8304849), unfortunately does not help:

```
import pytest
import pathlib


class ContextPath:
    def __init__(self, pathstring):
        self.path = pathlib.Path(pathstring)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.path.mkdir()

    # The latter 3 args are just a boilerplate convention
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.path.rmdir()


@pytest.fixture
def some_resource():
    with ContextPath("i_want_to_be_deleted"):
        yield


def test_dummy_succeeds(some_resource):
    assert pathlib.Path("i_want_to_be_deleted").exists()
```

**Is there a way to have `pytest` execute the teardown part of the fixture, regardless of ending a debugging session?**

As a remark, the Matlab debugger exhibits the requested behavior.

## The Environment

I'm using pytest, which tells me that I'm on

```
platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.2, pluggy-0.13.1
```

Furthermore, I use the vs code August 2020 release with the [Test Explorer UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-test-explorer) and [Python Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter) extensions to run and debug the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement a context manager? This guarantees that the `__enter__` and `__exit__` method will be executed. Although I have not tested this with your exact setup, this might be a solution to your problem.

```py
import pathlib
import pytest


class ContextPath(pathlib.Path):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.mkdir()

    # The latter 3 args are just a boilerplate convention
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.rmdir()


@pytest.fixture
def some_resource():
    with ContextPath("i_want_to_be_deleted"):
        yield
```

Comment: Subclassing `pathlib`'s classes doesn't work as shown in the answer atm, and it doesn't seem to be straightforward either (https://stackoverflow.com/q/29850801/ and https://bugs.python.org/issue24132). However, assinging a `pathlib.Path` object to an attribute of the class without inheritance works. Unfortunately, the context manager's `__exit__` doesn't get executed in this case as well, which makes me wonder (context managers' `__exit__` always gets executed after ending debugging, right?).

Comment: updated question, including your suggested improvement