Subclass of pathlib.Path doesn't support "/" operator
I'm attempting to create a subclass of pathlib.Path that will do some manipulation to the passed string path value before passing it along to the base class.
class MyPath(Path):
    def __init__(self, str_path):
        str_path = str_path.upper() # just representative, not what I'm actually doing

        super().__init__(str_path)

However, when I try to use this:
foo = MyPath("/path/to/my/file.txt")
bar = foo / "bar"

I get the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'MyPath' and 'str'
I am using Python 3.12 which I understand to have better support for subclassing Path

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850801/subclass-pathlib-path-fails

If you look at the code for e.g. PosixPath, that class is defined as class PosixPath(Path, PurePosixPath):. When running your code, it seems to be looking for a method with_segments that you need to provide. I don't understand the details, your best bet is to single-step through the / code in a debugger to see what's missing.

Relevant: What’s New In Python 3.12 § pathlib: "Add support for subclassing pathlib.PurePath and pathlib.Path, plus their Posix- and Windows-specific variants."

It'd help to phrase the title as a question. If I could suggest: "How do I get a subclass of pathlib.Path to support the "/" operator?". For tips on how to write a good title, see [ask].

Beside the point, but if all the functionality of your class is in __init__, you should use a factory function instead: def my_path(str_path): return Path(str_path.upper()). I think this talk has some relevant points: Stop Writing Classes by Jack Diederich.

Oops, a factory function wouldn't make the result all uppercase like in chepner's answer. I didn't realize that would happen, my bad.

MyPath("foo") / "bar' goes through several steps:

It invokes MyPath("foo").__truediv__("bar"), which
Invokes MyPath("foo").with_segments("bar"), which
Invokes MyPath(MyPath("foo"), "bar"), which
Raises a TypeError because you overrode MyPath.__init__ to only accept a single additional positional argument, which
Causes MyPath.__truediv__ to catch a TypeError and subsequently return NotImplemented

Your __init__ method must be careful to accept multiple path components, not just a single string, and it must not assume that each argument is an actual string, but rather objects that implement the os.PathLike interface. (In particular, don't assume that a path component has an upper method. Call os.fspath on the component first to retrieve  a str representation that does have an upper method.)
Something like
import os

class MyPath(Path):
    def __init__(self, *paths):
        super().__init__(*(os.fspath(x).upper() for x in paths))

and thus
% py312/bin/python -i tmp.py
>>> bar
MyPath('/PATH/TO/MY/FILE.TXT/BAR')

Alternately, as others have alluded to, you can override with_segments to, for example, combine the segments yourself and pass the single result to MyPath, but I see no reason to restrict MyPath.__init__'s signature as you currently do.

Why path, *paths? Zero args should be acceptable too.

That's what I saw PurePathBase defines, presumably so that you can't define an empty path. But Path() is fine, so I'll double-check how those two work together and update the answer again.

(PurePath.__init__ doesn't even call PurePathBase.__init__, as an "optimization". I'm just going to follow its lead, though, and not worry about how or when PurePathBase.__init__ ever gets called.)

PurePathBase? Are you looking on Python 3.13?

No, just the implementation in pathlib/_abc.py, trying to find the definition of with_segments.

There is no pathlib._abc in Python 3.12, only pathlib.py.

Ugh, my bad. I'm in a local checkout of the cpython repository, and was assuming that main was the more stable branch compared to the 3.13 branch.
